# Regex to match a string that contains at least 3 dashes / hyphens

Tags: c#, regex

I have an email body. It contains several lines of text. I need to extract the first occurrence of a string that:

1. comes after a specific text
2. contains at least 3 dashes

The shape of the dashed string is unknown. It may contain letters and numbers of any number, i.e.: 
AA3A-123-NNN-D or 12-OOO-12455-AS

For example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec imperdiet porta libero ac imperdiet.

Nam enim nisl: aliquam ut feugiat vitae

**Specific text after which I need to search:** Etiam rhoncus **AAFA-12X-DDDD-12** metus risus
More text: foo

Target language is C#.

I've tried doing something like `([A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5})` but as you can see here I need to set the shape of the string which is not always known.

Comment: Well if they contain a range of possible characters per block (before each dash) in your regex you can change your {5} to {1,5} for 1 to 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lazy quantifier with `[\s\S]`:

```
(?:Specific\ text\ after\ which\ I\ need\ to\ search:)
[\s\S]+?\K
(\b\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b)
```

The `\b` is a word boundary, `\K` deletes everything to the left from the match.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pM1wE5/2).

Comment: you can use `(?s)` also instead of `[\s\S]`

Comment: thanks a lot, it's nice. It works if the string has only 3 dashes, but if more, eg: AA-B12-C333-D it does not match the parts after the 3rd dash

Comment: @Ashton add `\S*` in last like `\b\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\b\S*`

Comment: awesome! works. I learned something today. (Not to love regex just yet, but I'll buy it a drink). Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If your expression contains an unknown number of letters and numbers the best you can do is specify a range for your regular expression. I see in your examples the most a block has is 5 characters and least one has is 1 character.

So something like this will capture it,

```
([A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5})
```

Comment: thanks Fivestar. Jan's solution works closer to what I need. I appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: @Ashton No prob! That answer is much better mine is a fairly lazy regex I just editted yours haha. Good luck moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-){3,}[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. What this will do is match 3 or more groups of alphanumerics ending with a dash, followed by one that doesn't.

[Try it yourself on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cP3kX6/1).

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, I think this is going in the right direction too, but Jan's and rock321987's suggestion was closer. Appreciate your help!